# Retrieve data from Tuleap OpenALM to excel using VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, tuleap

I am trying to access Tuleap Open ALM via REST API.

I used the `/api/explorer/` to get necessary URL: "https://openalm.mycompany.com/api/v1/users?query=asmith&limit=10"

and I get correct output:

```
"[
  {
    ""id"": 12123,
    ""uri"": ""users/12123"",
    ""real_name"": ""Alex Smith"",
    ""username"": ""asmith"",
    ""ldap_id"": ""asmith"",
    ""avatar_url"": ""/themes/common/images/avatar_default.png""
  }
]"
```

But when I tried to get artifacts in the tracker I am getting an empty output.

URL: "https://openalm.mycompany.com/api/v1/tracker_reports/7426/artifacts?values=all&limit=50"

Output: `[ ]`

Here is my code:

```
Sub GetDataFromTuleapOpenALM()
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    myxml2 = "<platform>" & _
                "<login>" & _
                  "<userName>asmith</userName>" & _
                  "<password>getmein</password>" & _
                "</login>" & _
              "</platform>"

    strURL = "https://openalm.mycompany.com/api/v1/users?query=asmith&limit=10"
    'strURL = "https://openalm.mycompany.com/api/v1/tracker_reports/7426/artifacts?values=all&limit=50"

    objHTTP.Open "GET", strURL, myxml2
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/xml"
    objHTTP.send
    result = objHTTP.ResponseText
    Debug.Print (result)
End Sub
```

I am getting an empty output also when I try it in `/api/explorer/`.

Comment: Here are some examples showing how the credentials could be sent: via open params `objHTTP.Open "GET", strURL, False, "<username>", "<password>"`, via header `objHTTP.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " & Base64("<username>:<password>"))`, via request params, like `strUrl = "http://example.com/data?userid=<userid>&password=<password>"` or as a part of the URL `strUrl = "http://<userid>:<password>@example.com/data"`.

Answer (score 0):

possible issues could be
 - authentication : maybe your user info is publicly/ anonymously available but your artifacts are not.
- your report has no artifacts in it.

I'm slightly dubious about your Basic Authentication- you could try putting it directly in the url and see if that makes a difference i.e.

```
strURL = "https://asmith:getmein@openalm.mycompany.com/api/v1/users?query=asmith&limit=10"
```